# jQuery grid traversal methods

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a grid-based game where I want the user to be able to click on each selectable block in the grid to make the adjacent(horizontal,vertical,diagonal) blocks selectable and that block a selected block.All selected blocks should stay selected.I'm using two different classes called selectable and selected to tell the difference.Only the adjacent blocks of the current selected block should be selectable.Right now I want all selectable elements that are not adjacent to the current(last) selected element to return to their default state.Something like this(dark blue is selected and light blue is selectable):

[image]

I used some jQuery traversal methods but I'm stuck at a point and I can't figure out any efficient code.Please help!

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3DHMd/2/

HTML:

```
    <div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
<div class="grid">
<div class="column" id="column1">   
<div id="1" class="block"></div>
<div id="6" class="block"></div>
<div id="11" class="block"></div>
<div id="16" class="block"></div>
<div id="21" class="block"></div>
<div id="26" class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="column" id="column2">
<div id="2" class="block"></div>
<div id="7" class="block"></div>
<div id="12" class="block"></div>
<div id="17" class="block"></div>   
<div id="22" class="block"></div>
<div id="27" class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="column" id="column3">   
<div id="3" class="block"></div>
<div id="8" class="block"></div>
<div id="13" class="block"></div>
<div id="18" class="block"></div>
<div id="23" class="block"></div>
<div id="28" class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="column" id="column4">   
<div id="4" class="block"></div>
<div id="9" class="block"></div>
<div id="14" class="block"></div>
<div id="19" class="block"></div>
<div id="24" class="block"></div>
<div id="29" class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="column" id="column5">   
<div id="5" class="block"></div>
<div id="10" class="block"></div>
<div id="15" class="block"></div>
<div id="20" class="block"></div>
<div id="25" class="block"></div>
<div id="30" class="block"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    html,body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
cursor:default;
}

.outer {
    position: relative;
    display:table;
    width:100%; 
    height:85.25%;
    background-color:#959595;
}

.inner {
display:table-cell; 
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:85.25%;
}

.grid{
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border:0.7em solid #778086;
    width:93%; 
    height:90%;
    background-color: #B3B1B1;
    clear:both;    
}

.column{
width:20%;
height:100%;
float: left;
}

.block {
 width:100%;
 height:16.15%;
 border: 0.1em solid  #778086;
 text-align: center;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
line-height: 2.8em;
}

.selected {
    background-color:#2976A2; 
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.selectable {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    background-color:#8DBFC4; 
    color:#FFFFFF;
    }
```

JS:

```
    $('#1').addClass('selected');

$('#2,#6,#7').addClass('selectable');

$(document).on('click','.selectable',function() {
$(this).toggleClass('selected').toggleClass('selectable');
var ind=$(this).index();
$(this).prev().toggleClass('selectable');
$(this).next().toggleClass('selectable');
if (ind!=0)
{
$(this).parent().prev().children().eq(ind-1).toggleClass('selectable');
$(this).parent().next().children().eq(ind-1).toggleClass('selectable');
}
$(this).parent().prev().children().eq(ind).toggleClass('selectable');
$(this).parent().next().children().eq(ind).toggleClass('selectable');
$(this).parent().prev().children().eq(ind+1).toggleClass('selectable');
$(this).parent().next().children().eq(ind+1).toggleClass('selectable');
$(this).parents().children('.selected.selectable').removeClass('selectable'); $(this).parents().siblings().children('.selected.selectable').removeClass('selectable'); 
});
```

Comment: is the game logic complete

Comment: Yeah well it's like only the adjacent blocks to each selected block at a given moment are selectable blocks.The selected blocks remain selected blocks.

Comment: I just did this. http://jsfiddle.net/3DHMd/2/ But what I want to do is make all the other blocks which were selectable but now are not adjacent to the selected block,non-selectable again.

Comment: if a block is already selected, and it is adjacent to current clicked element will it be selectable again

Comment: No,selected blocks will remain selected blocks even if they are adjacent to the current selected block,which they will be anyway.All selected blocks remain the same.But blocks which are not selected and are adjacent to the current(last) selected block will become selectable.Sorry if I couldn't explain it well :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function markSelectable(el) {
    el.addClass('selectable');
}

var $grid = $('.grid')
$grid.on('click', '.selectable:not(.selected)', function() {
    var $this = $(this), ind = $this.index(), $parent = $this.parent(), count, filter;

    $('.selectable', $grid).removeClass('selectable');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    markSelectable($this.prev(':not(.selected)'));
    markSelectable($this.next(':not(.selected)'));

    count = ind == 0 ? 2 : 3;
    filter = '.block' + (ind > 1 ? ':gt(' + (ind - 2) + ')' : '') + ':lt('
            + count + '):not(.selected)';

    markSelectable($(filter, $parent.prev()));
    markSelectable($(filter, $parent.next()));
});

$('.block:first', $grid).addClass('selectable').trigger('click');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZauHW/4/)

Comment: Wow this is really good and much more concise than my code. +1 Which answer do I select though? :P

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this:

JS Code:

```
    $('#1').addClass('selected');

$('#2,#6,#7').addClass('selectable');

$(document).on('click','.selectable',function() {
$(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('selectable');
var ind=$(this).index();
$('.block').removeClass('selectable');
$(this).prev().addClass('selectable');
$(this).next().addClass('selectable');
if (ind!=0)
{
$(this).parent().prev().children().eq(ind-1).addClass('selectable');
$(this).parent().next().children().eq(ind-1).addClass('selectable');
}
$(this).parent().prev().children().eq(ind).addClass('selectable');
$(this).parent().next().children().eq(ind).addClass('selectable');
$(this).parent().prev().children().eq(ind+1).addClass('selectable');
$(this).parent().next().children().eq(ind+1).addClass('selectable');
$(this).parents().children('.selected.selectable').removeClass('selectable'); 
$(this).parents().siblings().children('.selected.selectable').removeClass('selectable'); 
$(this).parents().children('.selected').off('click');
$(this).parents().siblings().children('.selected').off('click');

});
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/3DHMd/3/